# read error ubuntu 16.04

Tags: magento-1.9, linux

As i am working on my system it gets Hang and when I restart my system it shows error on booting  ERROR=>"Read Error" as I googled it and I found that this comes because OS is corrupted. Can anyone help me out from this.I have no back of data inside the hard disk.can anyone tell me how to get backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to use alternative option as this is also happen for me
you should boot your system from a usb drive then back your data and if there is problem of boot loader then it will be fixed when you restat after booting.

this works for me try this once.

Comment: It is working for me.